# ISO 11649:2009 reference number validation in java

Tags: java, banking, onlinebanking

I'm wondering if there is a library in java that validates a string against **SEPA RF** reference number in payments.

I can of course implement one of my own according rules defined by **ISO
11649:2009(E)** standard but I would not like to reinvent the wheel. I'm not able to goole any decent library about this. Do you know of any implementation for this?

Comment: SEPA denotes geographical area participating in common EURO playments. You probably meant IBAN number validation. https://github.com/barend/java-iban

Comment: No. SEPA is more than just the geographical area. In order to have SEPA compliant payments several conditions have to be met. And I am pretty sure OP knows the difference between a reference and an account number.

Although my work is related to SEPA I have not yet come across a RF Creditor Reference. I'll ask around in my company.

Comment: @Daniele Torino tnx for the comment, for now we have implemented our own validation, actually it is quite simple but anyway I would prefer a common library for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is one in an API for creating Swiss QR codes ("QR Rechnung"):

> public static boolean isValidISO11649Reference​(java.lang.String reference)
>
> Validates if the string is a valid ISO 11649 reference number.
>
> The string is checked for valid characters, valid length and a valid
> check digit. White space is ignored.
>
> Parameters:
> reference - ISO 11649 creditor reference to validate
>
> Returns:
> true if the creditor reference is valid, false otherwise

https://www.codecrete.net/qrbill-javadoc/net/codecrete/qrbill/generator/Payments.html#isValidISO11649Reference(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Its more or less a simple calculation:

```
    final String ref = "123456789012345678901"; //21 characters max
    final String rf = "2715"; // RF converted to numbers
    String rfAdd = "01"; // assuming 01 are the check digits
    final BigInteger refint = new BigInteger(ref + rf + rfAdd);
    int mod = refint.mod(new BigInteger("97"))
                    .intValue();
    if (mod != 1) {
       mod = 99 - mod; // set mod to correct check digits
    }
    rfAdd = String.format("%02d", mod); // correct the check digits
    System.out.println("RF" + rfAdd + ref);
```

The result should be a valid Referencecode explained by this source
https://www.mobilefish.com/services/creditor_reference/creditor_reference.php